# Trivially copyable class - what has changed in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, trivially-copyable

[The standard says](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#1)

> A trivially copyable class is a class:
>
> (1.1) that has at least one eligible copy constructor, move
> constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator
> ([special], [class.copy.ctor], [class.copy.assign]),
>
> (1.2) where each eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy
> assignment operator, and move assignment operator is trivial, and
>
> (1.3) that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor ([class.dtor]).

Now, I am not completely sure what it means. Does it mean that it is enough to have one of these?
For example a class with trivial copy constructor and copy assignment operator and explicitly deleted move constructor and move assignment operator is trivially copyable, or it means that I have non-deleted "big 6" and every one of them is trivial?

If I read this literally, having just one constructor or assignment operator should be enough. It was the case before c++20 according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Trivially_copyable_class).
If nothing has changed (namely I still can have deleted assignment operators or constructors) why was the wording changed? What is the difference between pre c++20 and C++20 standard meaning?

## Update

The experiments (such as the one in the [answer by Spencer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73023233/12104460)) show that my guess was correct. What I do not understand - why change the wording in C++20 standard. Has anything actually changed?

A [link to c++17 definition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#6).

In c++17 the definition was:

> 6. A trivially copyable class is a class:
>
> (6.1) where each copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment
> operator, and move assignment operator ([class.copy], [over.ass]) is
> either deleted or trivial,
>
> (6.2) that has at least one non-deleted copy constructor, move
> constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator,
> and
>
> (6.3) that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor.

Are there any subtle differences between old definition and the new one?

Comment: "At least one" means that only one is enough. So only a trivial copy-constructor and a trivial non-deleted destructor is enough to make the class trivially copyable.

Comment: That's what experiments with `std::is_trivially_copyable` show... However, why change the wording then if nothing has changed? Admittedly, the old wording was much more clear.

Comment: I reworded the paragraph on cppreference so that readers can catch the changes more easily.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What is the difference between pre c++20 and C++20 standard meaning?

For pre-C++20 classes, none. For post-C++20 classes, the difference is constraints.

The old wording talked about special member functions being "non-deleted". The new wording talks about them being "eligible." Eligible is defined in [[special]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/class#def:special_member_function,eligible):

> An eligible special member function is a special member function for which:
>
> - the function is not deleted,
> - the associated constraints ([temp.constr]), if any, are satisfied, and
> - no special member function of the same kind is more constrained ([temp.constr.order]).

You can think of it as the C++17 rule only had the first bullet while the C++20 rule adds the next two bullets (C++17 didn't have constraints so these latter two bullets are trivially satisfied). The reason for this can be found in the paper that added this wording, [P0848 (Conditionally Trivial Special Member Functions)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0848r3.html) (my paper).

The goal is for this to do the right thing, which is that `optional<int>` is trivially copyable, `optional<string>` is copyable but not trivially copyable, and `optional<unique_ptr<int>>` isn't copyable:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct optional {
    // #1
    optional(optional const&)
        requires copyable<T> && trivially_copyable<T>
        = default;

    // #2
    optional(optional const&) requires copyable<T>;
};
```

Before P0848, both `#1` and `#2` were considered copy constructors of `optional<int>`, and because `#2` isn't trivial, it would fail the requirement that every copy constructor is trivial. But it doesn't matter that `#2` isn't trivial, since `#1` is really the only important copy constructor - and the new C++20 rules ensure that this is the case.

Specifically, `#2` isn't *eligible* because `#1` is more constrained, so we only care about `#1` for determining whether `optional<int>` is trivially copyable. That copy constructor *is* trivial, so we're fine. On the other hand, for `optional<string>`, the associated constraints on `#1` aren't satisfied (`string` isn't trivially copyable), so the eligible copy constructor is `#2`, which isn't trivial.

Comment: the most comprehensive answer with the sample of more constrained combinations

Answer (score 3):

You only need one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct S
{
    S() noexcept = default;
    S(S const &) noexcept = default;
    S(S &&) noexcept = delete;
    S &operator =(S const &) noexcept = delete;
    S &operator =(S &&) noexcept = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::boolalpha(std::cout);
    std::cout << "Trivially_copyable: " << std::is_trivially_copyable_v<S> << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

output for me, at Compiler Explorer:

```
Trivially_copyable: true
```

I tried this for several different compilers and C++17 and C++20 just in case, with the same output.

The wording changed to "eligible" between C++17 and C++20 because of the introduction of concepts.  Look at [the definition of an "eligible" copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor):

> A copy constructor is eligible if
>
> - it is not deleted, and
> - its associated constraints, if any, are satisfied, and
> - no copy constructor with the same first parameter type is more constrained than it.

C++20 constraints let the compiler make a choice between overloads with the same parameters.  So in order for a copy constructor to be eligible, the "most constrained" copy constructor has to be deleted or trivial.

I've tried to contrive a template class that is trivially copyable for some specializations but not others, but with no success yet.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between pre c++20 and C++20 standard meaning?

Before C++20, a copy/move constructor/assignment operator had to be **non-deleted and trivial**. Since C++20 it's supposed to be **eligible and trivial**:

> A copy constructor is eligible if
>
> - it is not deleted, and
> - its associated constraints, if any, are    satisfied, and
> - no copy constructor with the same first parameter type    is more constrained than it.

Essentially the difference is that post C++20 constructors/assignment operators need to meet the [concept requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), if any.